# Why vertical media queries are not popular or recommended?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm designing a mobile-first site and the thing is, height-based media queries could really benefit my page layout in many ways. But I am holding myself from using them because like more than 90% articles I've read about responsive design don't even mention vertical media queries.

Even mixin libraries exclude them like the one I use (Rupture). And here in SO they don't recommend using it. It really feels like it's a broken feature or has loads of compatibility issues...

I just noticed Instagram uses `min-height` on their mobile site So I thought maybe it's really safe to use them.

Comment: Vertical media queries are basically same as horizontal ones. I've never heard about these being any different. Why less popular? It's just because they are not as useful in most cases. Also mixing vertical and horizontal queries requires developer to be much more organised as it can get really messy very quickly.

Comment: In practice, most of the work done on the responsiveness of sites will concentrate on avoiding the horizontal scrollbar. So the width of the device is what matters. The majority of users don't mind having to scroll vertically; so it really isn't that important to know what the height of the screen is.

Comment: But that doesn't mean it is not _recommended_ to base your layout on the height of the screen; in fact, I can't remember ever having seen that it wasn't; only that the width is more important to focus on.

Comment: @MrLister I get your point but most of us think that if the width gets bigger then we are dealing with a larger screen size. But that's not always true, is it? What if the device is on landscape mode?

Comment: @MrLister or If we have some absolute positioning like in my case. You see Twitter, Tumblr, IG, and many sites like that do have them but they fit to any screen size. I can't figure out how they do that though.